Ubuntu - When clicking task bar, open or activate app in current window
I have a multiple monitor setup.
When I click an icon in the task bar to activate an open app it will be selected in the window where it is currently open.
Is there a way to move it to the active window when I click the icon in the taskbar.
ie - clicking taskbar icon for app in display 1 will open it/ bring it to the fore and move it to display 1?
